# Trouve l'intrus dans la série

Tags: vocabulaire, jeux

Quel est l'intrus dans la série

- courbé
- arrondi
- incurvé
- bombé
- voûté
- courbatu

et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**En fait, il y a un double intrus.**

Les 5 premiers dérivent d'un verbe (transitif) et sont des participes passés utilisés comme adjectifs et ont un sens similaire.

**Seul courbatu est un adjectif pur, et signifie *atteint de courbature*.**

On peut être *courbatu* car on est (on a le dos) *courbé*, *voûté*, ...